# How to create a picture slideshow in a sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, picture-library

I am really new in the sharepoint 2013 environment and I want to create a slideshow of pictures I put in a picture library. I manage to create one with the Picture Library Slideshow Web Part but I'm having a hard time customizing it like the picture shown is not the original size, it is positioned to the left part of the page and so on. So Is there a way to create a slideshow of images by coding it? or if not is there a way to edit the picture slideshow web part I created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOTB Picture Library SlideShow WebPart is known for having trouble with spacing and customisation even if you set the height and width it doesn't render properly. You will need to add additional CSS (you can add a content editor web part and add CSS) to customise size and style. Have a look [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1e63661f-0183-44e7-843a-cca58a20cddc/remove-empty-space-in-picture-library-slideshow-web-part?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) (although for 2010, but approach would be the same i.e. finding an appropriate ID through F12 developer tools.

I would prefer [Image Slider with SharePoint 2013 Search Results Web Part](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/image-slider-with-sharepoint-2013-search-results) over the OOTB SlideShow webpart.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly style your slideshow size and positioning with additional css styles or code a custom slideshow with JavaScript snippets available on the web.